# Is it possible to fill NSRect with a particular pattern using NSBezierPath?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbezierpath, nsrect

I'm curious if I can draw a NSRect using NSBezierPath and then fill it with some striped pattern so it looks something like the picture below?

[image]

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of

```
+ (NSColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(NSimage *)image
```

and fill the rect with the color .

```
[[NSColor colorWithPatternImage: patternedImage] set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:yourRect];
```

Comment: Something wrong with NSRectFill()?

Answer (score 0):

Yes — just create an NSColor with a pattern image and fill with that color.

Comment: Thank you so much Chuck! Would you mind elaborate a little bit more, I'm not that proficient with cocoa development yet?!